# Charge motion, still at time 0, in an electromagnetic field. Classical approach

Tags: electromagnetism

Let's have a stationary EM field. Put in it a positive charge of mass m in the initial position (0,0,0); free the charge with an initial velocity 0. 
The charge is submitted to the Electromagnetic force; so, I guess, it feels both the electric and magnetic force .
What 'll be the motion? And his trajectory?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force

Answer (score 0):

The question is not specif enough: you can't solve motion just with the information that the fields are stationary. If the fields are constant in space and orthogonal for instance, then the motion (ignoring the radiation of the accelerated charge) is a still quite complicate. You can solve it with a Lorentz force with a velocity $v=v(t)$ depending on time and the acceleration in the direction of the electric field $E$ is constant (therr is also the acceleration due to Lorentz force of course). Qualitatively the particle shall move in something similar to spirals (with the radius which changes on time) and in the directio on the electric field.

If the fields are othogonal with the "right" intensity then you get what is known as "velocity selector", since particles go straight only if their velocy is a specif one.

Changing configuration of fields motion changes as well...

Comment: I've not been sufficiently clear; with the words "stationary EM field" I meant actually a stationary EM waves.

Comment: If the EM wave is stationary the particle moves just for a few time as it was in the case I told you and then the motion is free.